# How to open report in a New tab using Got to URL Property in RDLC?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc

i have used "GO To Url" property of RDLC set to below value;

```
=parameters!ParamUrl.Value +"ReportUIs/MonthlyReport.aspx?SpecDate=" + Fields!SpecDate.Value.ToString() + "&TrainPK=" +  Fields!TrainNo.Value.ToString() + ""
```

And it works fine with same tab or form. I want make this URL opened in new tab or window?
How can i give like **Target=_blank** option for this ?

tried this; works well but issue with the main form(first form):->

```
="javascript:window.open('"+parameters!ParamUrl.Value +"ReportUIs/MonthlyReport.aspx?SpecDate=" + Fields!SpecDate.Value.ToString() + "&TrainPK=" +  Fields!TrainNo.Value.ToString() + "');"
```

Comment: the last expression given works fine for a new tab but it causes the first form also to load with the URL

Answer (score 10):

Set the "**HyperlinkTarget**" property of Report viewer to ->  `HyperlinkTarget="_blank"`